# programmatically get the time mobile screen was active in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, device

I am working a core Blackberry application in which I need to detect the time for which screen is active and not blank or not coming in sleep mode after left un-touched.

I search alot, but didn't anything interesting. Please provide me some useful stuff or snippet so that i can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [onExposed](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onExposed%28%29) and [onObscured](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onObscured%28%29) method of the class [Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html).

> protected void ***onObscured()***
>
> Invoked when this screen is obscured. A Screen is obscured when it is
>   was the topmost and is no longer by means of:
>
> - a new screen pushed on the display stack
> - a global screen is displayed above this screen
> - this screen's application goes into the background
> - this screen is pushed and it is deemed obscured by the above rules

> protected void ***onExposed()***
>
> Invoked when this screen is exposed. A Screen is exposed when it becomes the topmost by
>   means of:
>
> - a screen is popped off the display stack
> - a global screen is popped
> - this screen's application receives foreground
> - this screen is pushed and it is deemed exposed by the above rules